# Using virtual directory in url in htaccess file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

We are trying to have virtual folder after a particular url.  When the user reaches the virtual folder, It should display the index page instead of 404 error.

We have tried to use Rewrite rule in .htaccess file but it continues to show 404 error.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^p/(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [R=301,L]
```

In the url address bar, when the user types for example:
https://ecitizen.in/p/002. '002'is a virtual directory. It should load the index page of https://ecitizen.in/p/index.php without actually redirecting or changing the actual url typed. Right now when we type this url: https://ecitizen.in/p/002 with above said code, it is displaying 404 not found error

Comment: *"without actually redirecting or changing the actual url typed"* - remove `R=301` from the flags, that's making the redirect an HTTP 301.

Comment: Is this .htaccess file in the `p` directory or at the document root? If it's in the `p` directory you'll want to remove that from the match, if it's at the docroot you'll want to add `/p/` before index.php - e.g.: https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=1521a193-1ebf-5ba3-998e-5155ae3ba971

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends on whether this *.htaccess* file is at the document root or in that `/p` directory - either way though, you'll want to remove the `R=301` flag (that's what's making it into an HTTP 301 redirect).

**If the .htaccess file is as the docroot**

You'll need to map the `/p` directory into the rewrite.

```
RewriteRule ^p/(.*)/?$ /p/index.php?/$1 [L]
```

**If the .htaccess file is in the /p directory**

You'll need to remove the `/p` directory from the match.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks. Its working, but when i echo PHP_SELF in the page, it has excluded the 'virtual directory'. My requirement is also to  echo the virtual directory

Comment: Thanks. Resolved. I used $_SERVER ['REQUEST_URI']. It worked. I'm ticking your answer as the right one.